# how to change color of part of actionbar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles

my actionbar title is 2 word, i want to use 2 color for each word like this image :
[image]

now i`m using these code to change text color:

```
    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">45dp</item>
        <item name="actionBarSize">45dp</item>


        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
         <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar</item>
        <item name="background">@color/actionbar</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
     </style>
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>
```

but those code change both word color, so how can i do that?

Comment: use tool bar instead of action bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in your `oncreate()`

```
String text = "<font color='#F44336'>Your</font><font color='#FF9800'>Title</font>";

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate style for your subtitle.
Add this in bottom:

```
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.SubTitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Then change the

```
<item name="@android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>

<item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.SubTitleTextStyle</item>

<item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.SubTitleTextStyle</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with spannable

```
    String part1 = "Actionbar ";
    String part2 = "TITLE";
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(part1 + part2);
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), part1.length(), part1.length()+part2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// Update the action bar title with the spannable instance
    getActionBar().setTitle(s);
```